# Localized Storyboard: How to add new content?

Tags: ios, localization, xcode4.5, uistoryboard

I just started to use Localization in my app. I now see that there are multiple "MainStoryboard.storyboard" files, for each language one. I can easily change the text.

But what happens when I want to extend the storyboard with a new view? I expected it to be duplicated into all storyboard files, but that doesn't seem to be the case? 
Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Base Internationalization (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW2)). The idea is to build up a flexible UI in your storyboards and then rely on Xcode / iOS to substitute in appropriate text. Instead of having a storyboard per language, you would have a single Base storyboard and a set of language strings files.